# What are scheduler Activations?

Tags: multithreading

I am reading about multi-threading in Peter Baer Galvin's *Operating System Concepts*; I don't understand the following topics:

- How LWP (virtual processor) works and schedules threads or maps to kernel threads
- Why LWP are important
- Many-to-many mapping